# R: using gsub in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, gsub

Low level R user here.

I have 3 population data frames (low.proj, med.proj, high.proj) with the exact same number of rows and columns I'm trying to clean and reshape.

I want to eliminate some extra commas in the country column all three of the frames so I'm trying this loop with gsub:

```
for(i in c("low.proj", "med.proj", "high.proj")){
    i$Country <- gsub(",","",i[,"Country"])
    }
```

When I run this I get the error "Error in i[, "Country"] : incorrect number of dimensions"

When I run the code without the loop:

```
low.proj$Country <- gsub(",","",low.proj[,"Country"])
```

It works. What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to retrieve the contents of the object with the string contained in `i` use `get()` to put new data in that object use `assign`

```
for(i in c("low.proj", "med.proj", "high.proj")){
  tmp <- get(i)
  tmp$Country <- gsub(",","",tmp[,"Country"])
  assign(i, tmp)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're indexing the wrong variable:

```
i$Country <- gsub(",","",i[,"Country"])
```

`i` is a string, so `i$Country` doesn't have any meaning.

Comment: This could be improved by showing what would be correct to do, instead of just listing what is wrong.